# Use Subquery and Concatenate Multiple Columns into JSON Object

Tags: sql, json, oracle

**CONTEXT**

Using DBeaver / Oracle, I'm trying to match a Parent table and show return all children related to that parent as one column value.

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
--Parent Table--
ID    NAME    GENDER
1     John    M
2     Ruby    F

--Child Table--
REL_ID    NAME    GENDER   AGE
1         Lucy    F        10
1         George  M        9
2         Angie   F        14

**REL_ID = ID
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
ID    NAME    CHILD
1     John    [{"REL_ID": 1, "NAME": "Lucy", "AGE": "10"}, {"ID": 1, "NAME": "George", "AGE": "9"}]
2     RUBY    [{"REL_ID": 2, "NAME": "ANGIE", "AGE": "14"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query and JSON functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY 'REL_ID' VALUE c.rel_id,
                    KEY 'NAME'   VALUE c.name,
                    KEY 'AGE'    VALUE c.age
                  )
                )
         FROM   child c
         WHERE  c.rel_id = p.id
       ) AS child
FROM   parent p
```

Which, for the sample data (courtesy of @PonderStibbons):

```
create table parent(ID, NAME, GENDER) as
  select 1, 'John', 'M' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Ruby', 'F' from dual;

create table child(REL_ID, NAME, GENDER, AGE) as
  select 1, 'Lucy', 'F', 10 from dual union all
  select 1, 'George', 'M', 9 from dual union all
  select 2, 'Angie', 'F', 14 from dual;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | [{"REL_ID":1,"NAME":"Lucy","AGE":10},{"REL_ID":1,"NAME":"George","AGE":9}] |
| 2 | Ruby | [{"REL_ID":2,"NAME":"Angie","AGE":14}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVo7KgJw)